# sh script with Byte Order Mark

Tags: linux, sh, bom

Is the Linux "sh" able to run Unicode text script files with BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning?

I really need this and do not want to remove BOM.

Comment: UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: @grawity: should support any possible. Device runs with Busybox and supports sh or ash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat. Although the kernel will not recognize executable scripts with a `#!/bin/...` header if they also have an UTF-8 BOM, they should still be recognized by the parent shell itself (the traditional POSIX way), and they can still be run by manually invoking the shell interpreter:

```
sh myscript.sh
```

The shell will treat the BOM as part of the first line, so don't bother including the `#!` header, but instead make sure the script starts with a dummy command to consume it:

```
: 2>/dev/null
```

UTF-16 is not supported, whether with BOM or without.